# QT6 function overloading - QList redefinition of QVector

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, qt5, qt6

I have an compilation error "**error: redefinition of 'from_json'**" with that code:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

template<typename OwnType> void from_json(QVector<OwnType> &p)
{
    qDebug() << "QVector";
}

template<typename OwnType> void from_json(QList<OwnType> &p)
{
    qDebug() << "QList";
}
```

But i getting that compilation error only in **QT6**. In **QT5** that compilling and working successfully. Whats wrong?

**c++17 MinGW**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt6, `QVector` is just an alias for `QList`.